Why is my Shiny app not generating a plot?
I am attempting to generate a plot using variables in my server code that can be changed- I'm not sure if I am formatting this wrong and that is why a plot is not generating. My goal is to generate a line plot depending on a change in the 'mean sojourn time' and 'screen sensitivity' (these are my input widgets)- a change in this variable impact the values of x and y in my line plot. I want to be able to visualize how changing these variables will change the line plot.
This is my current code:
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
ui <- fluidPage(numericInput(inputId = 'y',
                  label = 'Mean Sojourn Time',
                  value = '5',
                  min = '1'),
                numericInput(inputId = 'pr',
                             label = 'Screen Senst',
                             value = '0',
                             min = '0',
                             max = '1',
                             step = '0.25'),
                plotOutput(outputId = 'lineplot')
                )

server <- function(input,output) {
  output$lineplot <- renderPlot({
  t_0 <- 40 
  startage <- 50
  n <- 100000
  k <- 30
  x <- 0.58
  lambda <- -(log(1-x))/k 
  y <- input$y
  mu <- 1/y
  num.screen <- 1:10
  pr <- input$pr
  
  counter <- 2
  repeat{
    id <- c()
    t_p <- t_0 + rexp(n, lambda)
    t_c <- t_p + rexp(n, mu)
    
    newdf <- data.frame(t_p, t_c) %>% 
      filter (t_c <= 100)
    cancerdf <- mutate(newdf, id = row_number()) %>% 
      select(id, everything()) 
    
    result <- reframe(cancerdf, screen.num = num.screen,.by = id)
    ddset <- cancerdf %>% 
      right_join(result, by= id) %>% 
      mutate(screen.age = screen.num + startage - 1) %>%
      filter(t_c > startage,
             t_c > screen.age) %>%
      filter(t_c > screen.age | t_c-screen.age <= 1) 
    ddset$test.result = rbinom(nrow(ddset), 1, prob = pr)
    
    new.ddset <- ddset %>% 
      filter(cumsum(test.result)<=1  
             & test.result==cummax(test.result), .by=id) %>%
      filter(t_p < screen.age, t_c > screen.age) %>% 
      group_by(id) %>%
      mutate(screen = (ifelse(test.result == 1 & t_c > screen.age, 1,0))) %>% 
      mutate(interval = ifelse(t_c - screen.age > 1, 0,1 ),
             interval = ifelse(screen == 1 & interval == 1, 0,interval)) 
    
    simulation.sensitivity <- new.ddset %>% 
      group_by(screen.age) %>% 
      summarise(screen = (sum(screen)),
                interval = (sum(interval)),
                sensitivity = (screen/ (screen + interval)))
    counter <- counter - 1
    if (counter == 0) {
      break
    }
simulation.sensitivity %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = screen.age, y= sensitivity)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE)+
    theme_minimal()
  }})
  return(output$lineplot)
}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)


I don't get an error, but no plot is rendering.

Because you are not returning a plot. Assign the plot inside the repeat{} to something and return this outside, depending on what you want.

I tried this by adding return(output$lineplot) to the code but still no plot rendered.

This won't work. The problem is that you define the plot in simulation.sensitivity %>% ggplot(aes(x = screen.age, y= sensitivity)) + ...  and this is not assigned to something inside the repeat block. Say e.g. plot <- simulation.sensitivity ... at the end of the repeat block and then, after the repeat block inside the renderPlot, just write plot. This returns the plot and you will see something. However, I am not sure whether the content of the plot is correct, you have to check this.

Wow that worked! Thank you!
